# Create RESTful resource manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in order to better understand how RESTful works in Rails and thus become better at producing such code, i would like to manually create a resource from scratch. I generally know how to setup routes, controllers and the likes, but i would be interested in checking out some tutorial(s) that describe just that in detail.

Do you happen to know of anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first advise you to get your REST concepts cleared. In my opinion, REST is fairly misunderstood concept in the community. I would recommend understanding it first without sticking to rails or any other technology for that matter. Ryan Tomayko has written [a killer blog post](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife) about it. You also might want to read [Roy Fielding's paper](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), if you are into it.

Once you understand the concept clearly, implementing it in a technology is not so hard. For rails, create a blank controller and start adding the actions one by one based on your understanding of REST. Think about exactly are you doing in the action. Are you fetching the data and showing it to the user? In that case, you need to make sure that the action can only be called with a `HTTP GET` verb. Are you updating a record in that action? You probably should only be accepting a `HTTP PUT` verb for that action and so on... Here are some resources found on some quick googling which look good to me.

http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2008/02/04/restful-rails-part-i/
http://s3.amazonaws.com/ozonesoft.net_public/RESTfulRails.pdf

I would recommend reading the [standard documentation of routes in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). I think that's enough. But to understand what makes an app a RESTful app and what doesn't is the key.

Comment: thank you for the very interesting resources. I've started writing my custom resources already.